# Changing Button UI in Android

Tags: android, button, custom-controls, setbackground

I am trying to customize a Button UI in Android.
I tried the following things:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor
btn.setBackgroundResource
btn.setBackgroundColor
```

But all of these are increasing the size of the Button, and because of that the Buttons near by can not be segregated (??).

Please suggest something.

Comment: how setting the background color increased the size of your button?

Comment: Thats what the question is.
Background is actually crossing the button size.

Comment: if your background drawable is bigger,try to fix the size of your button,just setting a background color won't  increase the size of your button in any case

Comment: if you are using any background image then only it will increase the size of the button.If you change only color then it will not change the size of the button.

Comment: background color never increases button size. Quite possible that drawable used to set as background is of large size.

Comment: There may be cases event if you just set a background color the theme which your app uses changes the button size. check that one and try  to use appcompat lite.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a Hover effect then you have to do this in your XML where button layout is like

```
Button
     android:id="@+id/xyz"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
     android:background="@drawable/general_btn_hover_effect"
     android:onClick="somefunction"
     android:text="@string/search_number"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     />
```

Notice `android:background="@drawable/general_btn_hover_effect"` there and then in @drawable folder make a   `general_btn_hover_effect.xml` and write this into it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_normal_bg" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_hover_bg" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_hover_bg" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank_normal_bg"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing background color can not change size of button. Maybe you changed size in xml layout. Check again